# assigning coordinate to a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm writing a MATLAB code, I encountered a problem: I have a `(2N+1)*(2N+1)` matrix for example `7*7`. I want to assign coordinate system to it such that the matrix center is the origin of coordinate system. I mean I want to assign `(0,0)` to row `4` and column `4` of matrix, `(1,0)` to row `4` and column `5` of matrix and so on. please help me
Thank you in advance

I want to generate a line of ones in all possible directions in a square matrix like this:

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

center of matrix is the origin. this line has 30 degree from horizontal axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a coordinate system"? That's a conceptual thing you can just do in your head... you'll have to be specific about the what it is you plan on doing with this matrix that depends on your coordinate system to get a sensible answer... at a first guess I would say that maybe `[X,Y]=meshgrid(-n:n,-n:n)` could be useful but it really depends on what you are planning to do next..

Comment: I just want to create a square matrix of zeros and set to 1 its elements in specific direction  (30 degree)

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to add a (manually worked) complete example output matrix. Otherwise it's very hard to know what you mean, do you mean a square of `1`s rotated or a line of `1`s and if a line then starting where and 30 degrees to what? Don't answer these questions in the comments but edit your answer and add an example matrix

Comment: @bahar If you want to edit your question to provide more detail you need to put that into the main section not the input block labeled `Edit Summary`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple mapping from the original matrix counting system to a customized one. Here I have built two cell matrices, representing the coordinates of the elements in the matrix.

[image]

Here I have done a simple mapping as follows:

```
for ii = 1:7
    for jj=1:7
        D{ii,jj} = C{ii,jj} - [4,4];
    end
end
```

Generally, for matrix of size `2*N+1`, you will do the following:

```
for ii = 1:2*N+1
    for jj = 1:2*N+1
        D{ii,jj} = C{ii,jj} - [N+1,N+1];
    end
end
```

where `C` is the original matrix and `D` is the mapped matrix. After you well-understood what I have done here, you can then replace the `for-loops` with more efficient functions such as `bsxfun`.